# What (and when) triggers chrome to ask the user to save the login credentials

Tags: google-chrome

I am working on a website and I noticed chrome has a weird behavior. When I save form values, chrome asks if I want to save the the username and password. The weird thing is that that form isn't a login form, that form doesn't even have a field named username or password. So what qualifications does chrome exactly look for a form  that makes it think that it is a login form? Or when is it triggered?
1) does it need to have a username and password field? 
2) is it looking for a specific keyword?
3) or is this a known bug for chrome?

Comment: it's about this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp
It's rely wired if Chrome generates autocomplete behavior by default. Please try switching it off by adding attribute `autocomplete="off"` on your `form` or `input` element.